# Reusing Jest unit tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to test a couple of database implementations using Jest. To help test these implementations, I first came up with a set of unit tests against an API that both implementations are expected to implement.

I'm currently struggling with passing the two implementations to the test suites.

Below is a (dummy) MongoDB implementation in its simplest form:

```
class MongoDB {
  async query () {
    console.warn(`This is a dummy function.`)
  }

  async connect () {
    // The real connect takes some time..instead we just simulate it
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, 300)
    })
  }
}
```

And here's a small snippet of my tests:

```
let db
beforeAll(async () => {
  db = new MongoDB()
  await db.connect()
  console.log(`mongoDB ready`)
})

async function testDB (db) {
  describe('Basic', async () => {
    test('Valid instance', async () => {
      expect(db).toBeTruthy()
      expect(db.query).toBeTruthy()
    })
  })
}

describe('Tests', async () => {
  console.log(`Running testDB`)
  testDB(db) // Have also unsuccessfully tried changing this to: return testDB(db)
})
```

My goal with this approach is to wrap all my tests inside the `testDB` function and simply call it with various implementations. For example, `testDB(new MongoDB())` and `testDB(new MemoryDB())` and so on.

This doesn't seem to work as expected, however.
The above code results in an error stating that:

```
  ● Tests › Basic › Valid instance

    expect(received).toBeTruthy()

    Expected value to be truthy, instead received
      undefined
```

The order of the `console.log` statements seems to suggest that the tests are running *before* `db` was initialized.

```
  console.log mongo.test.js:20
    Running testDB

  console.log mongo.test.js:7
    mongoDB ready
```

This entire example along with the resulting output can be [reproduced on repl.it](https://repl.it/@gurupras/testsuite-runs-before-beforeAll).

How can I reuse unit tests to test multiple implementations without resorting to duplicating the tests and maintaining two versions?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Faced same need today. Here is the way, adapted from typescript, but you get the idea:

```
// common/service.test.js
export const commonServiceTests = (name, impl) => {
  describe(`Common tests for ${implName}`, () => {
    // pile your tests here
    test('test1', () => { ... });
    test('test2', () => { ... });
    test('test3', () => { ... });
  });
}

// just to avoid warning, that no tests in test file
describe('Common tests for CommonService implementations', () => {
  test('should be used per implementation', () => {});
});
```

And for your each implementation:

```
// inmemory/service.test.js
import { commonServiceTests } from '../common/service.test';
import ...; // your implementation here

const myInMemoryService = ...; // initialize it

commonServiceTests('InMemory', myInMemoryService);
```

Then all tests defined in `common/service.test.js` will be executed within each implementation test.

In case your initialization is `async` (which is most likely), then your shared tests should be `async` as well. Then:

```
// common/service.test.js
export const commonServiceTests = (name, impl: Promise) => {
  describe(`Common tests for ${implName}`, () => {
    // pile your async tests here
    test('test1', async () => {
      const svc = await impl;
      return await svc.doSomthingPromisy();
    });
    test('test2', () => { ... });
    test('test3', () => { ... });
  });
}
```

Comment: I used this exact flow and it worked great with `jest`, but as soon as we tried to use this method with `playwright-test` for test annotations (skip, slow, etc.) it hangs.

Comment: Appears that no need to enable the empty test to avoid warnings, e.g. just skip it `test.skip('should be used per implementation', () => {});`.